# MySQL search in multiple columns that contain substring of search term

Tags: mysql, sql, search, full-text-search

I created a database table containing customers. Users of the application should be able to do searches in that table.
The table definition is as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `Customers` 
(
      `Id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `Firstname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Insertion` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Lastname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `ClientNumber` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
      `DateCreated` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
       -- More columns...
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
    
ALTER TABLE `Customers`
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Id`);

ALTER TABLE `Customers` 
    ADD FULLTEXT KEY `search_fulltext` (`Firstname`,`Lastname`,`ClientNumber`);
    
ALTER TABLE `Customers`
    MODIFY `Id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Desired result:

When a user searches for customers, the application looks for matches in columns `Firstname`, `Lastname`, and `ClientNumber`. When searching for 'John Doe', all rows containing any substring of that search term in any of the columns Firstname, Lastname, ClientNumber should be selected. <sub>(For the principle of the question, the ClientNumber column can be put in the background).</sub>

**My attempts**

The following query was my first try:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Customers 
WHERE Firstname LIKE CONCAT('%', :searchText, '%') 
   OR Lastname LIKE CONCAT('%', :searchText, '%') 
   OR ClientNumber LIKE CONCAT('%', :searchText, '%') 
LIMIT 0, 10
-- LIMIT here could be any limit.
```

When the user searches for a string that exactly appears as a substring in a column, it works as expected.

Say, a customer's person name is: *John Doe* (`Firstname`=John, `Lastname`=Doe)
When the user enters the search term 'John', or 'Joh', or 'Jo', it matches in the `Firstname` column. If the user enters search term 'Doe', it matches in the `Lastname` column. Both cases return the expected rows.

The problem occurs when the search text is a full name, like: 'John Doe'.
Despite that this search text contains possible matches in multiple columns, no rows are selected.

I realized the query is not suitable for what I want to achieve, so I tried to create a `FULLTEXT` index on the `Firstname`, `Lastname` and `ClientNumber` columns. It turns out this only works for values that satisfy the match on each single column. Looking for a full name still doesn't work.

This is the fulltext query I'm using:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Customers 
WHERE MATCH (Firstname, Lastname, ClientNumber)
    AGAINST('John Doe' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

This query does not solve my problem too.

So in a shorter sentence: The user must be able to search by full name, while the name is split over multiple columns.

Another option I can think of by myself, is creating an extra column in the table, just store the full name as a single string, and use that column to do searches.

<sub>In the future we'd also like to support searching with texts that are very similar to some value. So when a user searches for 'Peter Johnsson', it also selects rows containing 'Pete Johnson' (single r/s). But maybe that's too far from the context of the question.</sub>

Comment: Maybe concatenate the name fields and search that calculated field? Maybe select customer from a combobox?

Comment: @June7 For a small number of records in the table, a combobox could be considered. But when there are many records it would be impractical  to select everything from the table to fill a combobox.
Concatenating fields in the WHERE clause could be an option but seems to be a bit slow.

Comment: Why would many records be impractical? I have comboboxes that list thousands of items.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct answer to your question, but there are many solutions for your use case, those are some of them :

- Manipulate the text that you want to match and build a more expanded query, ex:

```dart
String[] splittedSearchTextBySpace = searchText.splite(" ");

String whereClause = "";
foreach(String word : splittedSearchTextBySpace){
    whereClause =
        whereClause +
        """Firstname LIKE '%:word%' OR
        Lastname LIKE '%:word%' OR
        ClientNumber LIKE '%:word%'"""
        + " OR ";
}

whereClause = whereClause.substr(0,-4) // remove last " OR "

cosnt query = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE "
    + whereClause +
    " LIMIT 0, 10";

callDB(query);

// this is just an example, you could do more than that
```

- Depending on the programming language that you are using, you will find many libraries/packages that provides search utilities and covers the commune use cases that you mentioned and more, ex :

  - Java : Lucene ...
  - Php : Tntsearch ...
  - ...
- You could also go beyond libraries, and use service/search-engines (PAAS or self hosted once) that provides search utilities, which you will connect to, as you do with your database service, such as :

  - elasticSearch
  - Algolia
  - Solr
  - ...

#### Bonus:

- Most of those service and libraries use a data structure called **inverted index**.
- Some related key words: *stemming, indexations, n-grams, fuzzy-search, full-text-search, tokenizers, ranking algorithms, Bm25 ..*
- To observe the score given by mysql Full-Text Search, use :

```sql
SELECT 
  id, 
  MATCH(Firstname, Lastname, ClientNumber) 
    AGAINST('John Doe' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS score 
FROM demo
```

- Take a look at `IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE WITH QUERY EXPANSION`, another mysql Full-Text Search mode.